# Is there a "functional if" in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, ternary-operator

Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
    if(mydata$alive[i]) { mydata$result[i] = mydata$alive_value; }
    else { mydata$result[i] = mydata$dead_value; }
}
```

That would be along the lines of

```
mydata$result <- func_if(mydata$alive,mydata$alive_value,mydata$dead_value)
```

Does something like that exist?

Comment: Yep, it's in the _See Also_ section of `help("if")`.

Comment: I think `ifelse` should work.

Comment: FWIW, it is often faster to assign the "default" value and then subset for the other case.  e.g. `mydata$result=mydata$alive_value; mydata$result[!mydata$alive]=mydata$dead_value`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `ifelse`. Documentation: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html.

```
mydata$result <- ifelse(mydata$alive, mydata$alive_value, mydata$dead_value)
```

Comment: More compactly: `within(mydata, result <- ifelse(alive, alive_value, dead_value)`.